# convert min, sec to a 0.xxx notation in c#

Tags: c#

I am new to c#. For school I have to make an exercise that converts the hours, minutes and seconds to a numeric value. So 37 min and 30sec becomes 0.625. Anyone know how to do this?

thanks a lot

Comment: Why does 37 min and 30 sec becomes 0.625? [Start here](http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/925741/Programming-with-C-----101.htm)

Comment: You need to specify the units for the result value. In your case, it will be hours I assume.

Comment: rene i thing 0.625 hours

Answer (score 3):

```
var duration = new TimeSpan(0, 37, 30);
string s = duration.TotalHours.ToString("0.###");
// s === "0.625"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, this is what I was looking for, but I have one more question: can this (0, 37, 30), be replaced by variables? In the assignment it was the idea that the user should give the hours, min and sec, and this had to be converted? Like I said, I am really new to this :)

Comment: @user2485608 absolutely; I was just taking the numbers from the question; `new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds)` is fine

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want hours, minutes and seconds to be converted to hours, you would do it like this:

```
double result = hours + minutes/60.0 + seconds/(60.0 * 60.0);
```

This is because a minute is 1/60th of an hour and a second is 1/3600th of an hour (3600 == 60 * 60) so the calculation uses simple scaling.

I'm thinking that you will need to show these kinds of calculations rather than using TimeSpan, if the teacher is looking to see if you understand the conversion logic.

Answer (score 1):

Won't provide a copy/paste ready solution (homework :-p), but the `TimeSpan` class has everything you need: `Parse` methods and constructors to build a `TimeSpan` from various times (hours, minutes,...) and properties to return results as minutes, hours...

Answer (score 0):

You will first want to convert the hours, minutes and seconds to a total number of seconds. Then you can compare that to the number of seconds in one hour. Take care when doing integer devision, you will first have to convert to a double!